# inspecting variables while debugging on resin

Tags: jsp, debugging, resin

I have some JSP code. I use resin server. I need to debug the jsp file. I successfully can connect to debug through dt_socket on Eclipse but eclipse does not show the content of the variables on debug time.

How can I overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

try to look for them in

```
pageContext / session / session / attributes
```